# How to implement a Reactive Restful API service based on webflux and Netty?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I want to implement a RESTful API service based on Webflux and Netty, and I have found some implementation demos on the official website and the Internet, but according to the current implementation method. I tested it on Jmeter and it doesn't seem to work very well, I wonder if it's a problem with my implementation, or if it's a problem with my thinking。

**application.yml**

```
Server:
  port:10001
spring:
  r2dbc:
    url:r2dbc:mssql://localhost:1433/TutorialDB
    username:sa
    password:123456
    pool:
      max-size:32
      max-idle-time:2m
      max-life-time:10m
      acquire-retry:3
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>r2dbc-pool</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>r2dbc-mssql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.asyncer</groupId>
      <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Repository**

```
public interface DeviceTypeDetailRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<DeviceTypeDetail, Long>{ 
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class DeviceTypeDetailServiceImpl implements DeviceTypeDetailService {

    private final DeviceTypeDetailRepository deviceTypeDetailRepository;
    
    public DeviceTypeDetailServiceImpl(DeviceTypeDetailRepository deviceTypeDetailRepository) {
        this.deviceTypeDetailRepository = deviceTypeDetailRepository;
    }
    @Override
    public Flux<DeviceTypeDetail> FetchAll(){
        return deviceTypeDetailRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/devicetypedetail")
public class DeviceTypeDetailController {
@Autowired
private DeviceTypeDetailService deviceTypeDetailService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public Flux<DeviceTypeDetail> FetchAll() {
        return deviceTypeDetailService.FetchAll();
    }

}
```

**Jmeter Aggregate Report --Webflux**
Number of Threads = 1000     Ramp-up = 1     loop Count = 100

[image]

**Jmeter Aggregate Report --MVC**
Number of Threads = 1000     Ramp-up = 1     loop Count = 100

[image]

I wonder if it's the wrong way I've implemented it or what's the case.

Comment: aparentloy you have a mvc implementation as well, what is different. Your dependencies worry me as there are a lot of versions in there, which shouldn't be there. I also wonder are you running JMeter on the same machine as the app as that will influence your results heavily.

Comment: Yes, my MVC application, my WebFlux application, and Jmeter all run on the same PC，My MVC application is very simple, I also make a RESTful API service, they all access the same data table in the same MSSQL database, and they all do the findAll() operation。

Comment: And  I moved the JMeter  to another PC today, but the performance of WebFlux is still relatively inferior compared to MVC.

Comment: You are mixing various versions of reactor. Spring Boot manages the bom of project reactor which manages the versions, you should specify that. Ideally you should have no versions in there at all for the libraries you are using. Nor should you include the `reactor-core` etc. dependencies as those already come in through `spring-boot-starter-webflux`.

Comment: Okay, I have removed redundant dependencies, and the `version` tag, and kept only four dependencies:`spring-boot-starter-webflux`,  `spring-data-r2dbc`, `r2dbc-pool`, and `r2dbc-mssql`.  The version of `spring-boot-starter-parent` is set to 3.1.2. Afterward, I conducted the same tests using JMeter, but it seems that the performance has not improved.

Comment: Furthermore, I noticed that a few threads from the JMeter test may not release automatically. I have to click the stop button to end the test, and when I do, the WebFlux application reports some warnings and errors like this: `[WARN] An exception has been observed post termination, use DEBUG level to see the full stack: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` and `[ERROR] Operator called default onErrorDropped`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I give up on using the combination of WebFlux + R2DBC. It's possible that R2DBC is causing a decrease in throughput compared to MVC + JDBC. When I use Vert.x alone, it feels good, and there's a throughput improvement of 3-5 times.

Comment: This is a decision rather than an answer.